# ios, given an X/Y coordinate how to get the underlying view

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Use-case:** An application expose an http interface/'html page', that page is periodically polling the iOS app for the snap of the app UIWindow ( capturing the app screen ), the user consumes this interface using a standard web-browser, clicking w/ the mouse on the browser page should get translated to a tap on the app, upon mouse click, the client side html calls a websvc method on the app providing the x/y coordinates that were clicked, I need to translate these x/y coordinates to a UIView for which I can simulate a tap in using eg.

```
[buttonObj sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And thus, 
Given X/Y coordinate, how can I resolve the underlying view, eg. "UIVIew* getViewAtPosition(int x, int y)"

Comment: give us more details on what exactly you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want is called `hitTest:withEvent:`. Assuming you have some container view:

```
UIView *hitView = [self.container hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```

In most cases you pass `nil` as the event when used this way. There are ways to have hit testing behave differently based on the event by overriding `pointInside:withEvent:`, but that's not usually necessary. (See the docs if that is something that interests you.)